# How to make negative valued absolute positioned elements to scroll?

Tags: scroll, css-position

I am working on a project, on witch some elements are dinamically positioned to negative absolute values. There are no problems to scroll the parent element with positive absolute positioned elements, but I can not find solution to scroll and make visible negative absolute positioned elements. Is there any way to do that?

here is a [PEN](https://codepen.io/ordinath-the-sans/pen/ZdLWyv) I wrote to show what I mean.

```html
<div class="relative-positioned">
    <div class="negative-absolute-positioned">negative absolute positioned</div>
    <div class="positive-absolute-positioned">positive absolute positioned</div>
</div>
```

```css
.negative-absolute-positioned {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: -30px;
    background-color: darkslateblue;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.positive-absolute-positioned {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 1000px;
    background-color: darkslateblue;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.relative-positioned {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to do with negative abspos values, it has to do with overflow and the direction property as it relates to text and overflow on scroll container. In writing modes that go from right to left, using a negative value to move things past the left side of the container would actually make scrollable overflow appear.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction

If you want to see it in action, in your codepen, add...

```
body { direction: rtl }
```

All of a sudden your negative left value will be scrollable, towards the inline-end of the scroll container.

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#scrolling-direction

> Due to Web-compatibility constraints (caused by authors exploiting legacy bugs to surreptitiously hide content from visual readers but not search engines and/or speech output), UAs must clip the scrollable overflow region of scroll containers on the block-start and inline-start sides of the box (thereby behaving as if they had no scrollable overflow on that side).
>
> The viewport uses the principal writing mode for these calculations.

So this is all a long way of saying, no there is no way to do what you are hoping without mixing writing modes.